# Homeomorphisms of unit squares satisfying properties

Tags: general-topology, analysis

We were given the following problems in our topology course as fun, challenging problems (they are not homework, and we are incouraged to discuss with others)

Given $I=[0,1]$,

Problem 1:  Find a homeomorphism $f:I^2\rightarrow I^2$ such that

$f(0\times I)=0\times I$

$f(I\times 0)=(I\times 0) \cup (1\times I)$

$f((1\times I)\cup (I\times 1))=I\times 1$

Problem 2: Find a homeomorphism $g:I^2-$ { Open upper right box quadrant} $\rightarrow I^2$

Such that

$g(x,-1)=(x,-1)$ for all $x$

$g(1,x)=(1,x)$ for all $x$

$g(-1,x)=(-1,x)$ for all $x$

$g([-1,0]\times 1)=I \times 1$

**My thoughts on problem 1:**
Suffices to find compact bijective map that satisfies above properties.

Define
$f_1:0\times I\rightarrow I\times 0$ by $f_1(0,t)=(t,0)$

Now sure how to define $f_2:I\times 0\rightarrow (I\times 0)\cup (1\times I)$

$f_3:(1\times I)\cup (I\times 1)\rightarrow I\times 1$ by $f_3(1,t)=(t,1)$ and $f_3(t,1)=(t,1)$

Then glue all the maps together somehow.

How does one construct such formulas??

**For problem 2:** I guess for $g([-1,0]\times 1)=I\times 1$ we can define map $[-1,0]\rightarrow I$ that linearly scales everything.

Comment: Image of connected set via homeomorphism (or any continuous function) is connected. But $I \times 0$ is connected, while $(I \times 0) \cup (1 \times I)$ is not.

Comment: @mihaild $(I\times 0)\cup (1\times I)$ is a 'T' and therefore path connected.

Comment: Sorry, is $I$ open or closed ($(0, 1)$ or $[0, 1]$)?

Comment: @mihaild I=[0,1]

Comment: Okay, then it's indeed connected (but it's reflected L, not T).

Comment: What is "Open upper right box quadrant"?

Comment: @ronno The upper right quadrant is the first quadrant in the x-y axis. It is a box

Answer (score 1):

For problem 1, lets use polar coordinates with center $C = (\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2})$ and $\phi = 0$ in direction of positive on $x$ axis. Let $R(\phi)$ be distance from $C$ to border of the square on angle $\phi$ (for example, $R(0) = R(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$.

In this case, $I \times 0$ corresponds to $\phi$ from $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{7\pi}{4}$, $I \times 1$ to $\phi \in [\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}]$, $0 \times I$ to $\phi \in [\frac{3 \pi}{4}, \frac{5 \pi}{4}]$, and finally $1 \times I$ to $\phi \in [\frac{7 \pi}{4}, \frac{8\pi}{4}) \cup [\frac{0 \pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$.

Now, it's easy to define $f_\phi$ part of homeomorphism:

$$f_\phi(r, \phi) = \begin{cases}
\phi& \phi \in [\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}]\\
\phi + (\phi - \frac{5 \pi}{4})\cdot 2 \mod 2 \pi& \phi \in [\frac{5 \pi}{4}, \frac{7 \pi}{4}]\\
\frac{\phi + \frac{\pi}{4}}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\mod 2\pi & \phi \in [\frac{7 \pi}{4}, \frac{8 \pi}{4}) \cup [\frac{0\pi}{4}, \frac{3 \pi}{4}]
\end{cases}$$

Essentially, when we traverse border of the square, we have (angular) velocity $1$ on $0 \times I$, velocity $2$ on $I \times 0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ on $1 \times I \cup I \times 1$.

Now, to define $f_r$ we just linearly stretch old segment from center to border to a new one: $f_r(r, \phi) = r \cdot \frac{R(f_\phi(r, \phi))}{R(\phi)}$.

For problem $2$, you can use the same technique - choose an inner point from which you can "see" the entire border, introduce polar coordinates from it, write angular part of homeomorphism with given restrictions, and stretch every radius. But writing explicit formulas becomes harder with more complex shapes.

Comment: Cool thanks! very clear writing! I will look at it more in detail soon. I was wondering, can we take $f$ and $g$ to be diffeomorphisms or bilipschitz? (f and g are the homeomorphisms in the problems)

Comment: I think this $f$ is already 2-bilipschitz, and we can't get differentiability because image of smooth curve $I \times 0$ is not smooth.

Comment: Hi. I hope you are well. Few questions: (1). You said "finally $1\times I$ to $\phi\in [,]\cup [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ Is this right? (2). When you you construct $f_r$ and the $f_\phi$, how is $f$ is then constructed? Lastly, (3) what are the conversions from $(r,\phi)$ plane to $(x,y)$?

Comment: Also, how are $r$ and $R$ related?

Comment: 1. I think it is. Note that $\phi = 8\pi /4$ and $\pi = 0$ is the same point. 2. $f$ is defined as "point with polar coordinates $(r, \phi)$ goes to point with polar coordinates $(f_r(r, \phi), f_\phi(r, \phi))$, and origin goes to origin" (sorry for confusion with indices - $\phi$ in $f_\phi$  isn't variable, it's just to denote that we are talking about $\phi$-coordinate). 3. It's $(x, y) = C + (r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)$.

Comment: $r$ is polar coordinate, while $R$ is distance to border with some angle (it can be written explicitly, but doesn't matter). You can note that points $(R(\phi), \phi)$ are on the border of the square.

Comment: Last two questions:(4)  How did you check that $f$ is 2-bilipschitz? (5). The middle part of $f_{\phi}$ takes the angle from $[\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}]$ to $[\frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}]$ right?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to also ask: (6). I don't understand the construction of $f_r$. What does it do? Why not just $f_r(r,\phi)=R(f_{\phi}(r,\theta))$?

Comment: 4. You can check that transformation to polar coordinates and back is 2-lipschitz on any bounded set, and angle and radius components of $f$ are 2-lipschitz. 5. No, to $[5\pi / 4, 11 \pi / 4]$ - it is the part $I \times 0 \to (I \times 0) \cup (1 \times I)$.

Comment: 6. We essentially transform any segment from $C$ to border to some other segment from $C$ to border. But initial and result segments can have different length, and we stretch them accordingly. You construction doesn't work, because we want $f_r$ to depend on $r$, but $f_\phi$ doesn't depend on $r$. $f_r$ has property that $f_r(0, \phi) = 0$ - $C$ moves to itself, and $f_r(R(\phi), \phi) = R(f_\phi(r, \phi))$ - point on border moves to border.